# Go error when using custom cell editor: 'ag-grid-angular' is not a known element

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to create a custom cell editor as configured in the `columnDefs`:

```
cellEditorFramework: CustomEditorComponent
```

Below is the implementation of the custom editor:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './custom-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-editor.component.scss']
})
export class CustomEditorComponent implements ICellEditorAngularComp, AfterViewInit {
...
}
```

I also imported `AgGridModule` component in `@NgModule` as below:

```
imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([
        CustomEditorComponent
    ])
],
```

My goal is to display an `ag-grid` when I click on the cell to edit.  I'm able to popup the `div` but no `ag-grid` is displayed.

```
<div>
  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 500px; height: 150px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Instead, I got the errors below:

```
NG8001: 'ag-grid-angular' is not a known element:
...
NG8002: Can't bind to 'rowData' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
...
NG8002: Can't bind to 'columnDefs' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
```

I'm using Angular 10.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the module AgGridModule:

```
imports: [
    ...
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
]
```

Try to remove the `<ag-grid-angular></ag-grid-angular>` and just display a simple `<div>test sample</div>` in your popup.

Which angular version you are using? If it is before Angular 9, the popup component should be added in `entryComponents`.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: I'm using angular 10 already.  As mentioned, the popup is showing, but the grid won't show cause of the error.

Comment: Try remove CustomEditorComponent in AgGridModule.withComponents

Comment: Initially, I didn't put `CustomEditorComponent` in `AgGridModule.withComponents`.  I just did when you mentioned in the answer.  So same issue.

Comment: can you create a simple sample on stackblitz?

Comment: it's weird, when i import `ICellEditorAngularComp` using `import { ICellEditorAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';` i get the error... but when i used `import { ICellEditorAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular/ag-grid-angular';` it works.